# Sum value of multiples input number field jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have multiple input number fields with the same class, and i have to sum them   but when I try with my javascript i get always NaN result

```
var arrNumber = new Array(); //contain the number of specific input field

        var totale;
        $(".input-n-pro").bind('keyup mouseup', function () {
             totale = 0;
        $('.input-n-pro').each(function(){
        var this_num = $(this).val();
            totale = parseInt(this_num)+parseInt(totale);
        })
        console.log("totale="+totale);
});
```

The html of input is this, generated by php, one for every row of a table

```
<input type="number" name="<?php echo $data["name"];?>" min="0" max="500" placeholder="0" class="form-control input-xs input-n-pro" style="display: inline">
```

I don't know it won't work, it work with only js withous jquery but i have to get the id of every field to do that and i want to do that for everyone with the same class because they are dinamic fields

P.S. The other part of my work, is to get every name of those fields and store them so i can have an array in js where i have the name of input and his number value, but i don't know how to do because they are dinamic

Comment: i've edited the question

Comment: console.log($(this).val(), parseInt($(this).val()))

Comment: yeah, not in my file! just here, i'll edit

Comment: @epascarello it work in console, but if i try to sum them in total variable it give Nan

Comment: `const sum = [...document.querySelectorAll('.input-n-pro')].reduce((acc, val) => acc += Number(val.value) || 0, 0);`

Comment: Before you try the || hack (which will work but the result will be false), figure out each value of $('.input-n-pro') and why you get the NaN when parse it

Comment: I changed my answer, adding **arrNumber** to store names and values

Answer (score 3):

You probably parsing something that is not an integer. Then the parseInt won't work and returns NaN. If you sum a NaN, then it stays a NaN, example:

```js
// working testcase:
const testArray = ['2', '3', '4'];
let total = 0;
for (value of testArray) {
    total += parseInt(value);
}
// returns 9
console.log(total);

// your testcase:
const testArray2 = ['2', '3', 'notANumber'];
let total2 = 0;
for (value of testArray2) {
    total2 += parseInt(value);
}
// returns NaN since we are adding 2 + 3 + NaN = NaN
console.log(total2);
```

So the solution is to 'negate' the NaN by treating it as 0:

```js
    //  solution:
    const myArray = ['2', '3', 'notANumber', '4'];

    let total = 0;
    for (value of myArray) {
        // treat NaN, undefined or any falsey values as 0.
        total += parseInt(value) || 0;
    }

    //  returns 9
    console.log(total);
```

To integrate this concept in your code, you'll get something like:

```js
let total = 0;
$('.input-n-pro').each(() => {
  let valueInString = $(this).val();
  let actualValue = parseInt(valueInString) || 0;
  total += actualValue;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**bind()** has been deprecated => use **on**

```js
  arrNumber = [], //contain the number of specific input field
  totale    = 0;

  doTotale();    // first round

$(".input-n-pro").on('keyup mouseup change', doTotale);

function doTotale()
{
  totale = 0;
  arrNumber.length = 0;

  $('.input-n-pro').each(function()
  {
    let 
      name = $(this).attr('name'),
      val  = parseInt($(this).val(),10) || 0;

    arrNumber.push( {name, val });
    totale += val;
  })
  console.clear();
  console.log("totale =",totale);
  console.log("arrNumber =", JSON.stringify(arrNumber) );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
AA :  <input type="number"  name="AA" value="5"   class="input-n-pro" /> <br>
BB :  <input type="number"  name="BB" value="3"   class="input-n-pro" /> <br>
CC :  <input type="text"    name="CC" value="foo" class="input-n-pro" /> <br> <!-- lets insert one input that contains no number -->
DD :  <input type="number"  name="DD" value="2"   class="input-n-pro" /> <br>
EE :  <input type="number"  name="EE" value="11"  class="input-n-pro" /> <br>
FF :  <input type="number"  name="FF" class="input-n-pro" />
```

Comment: So much code for what can be done in two lines of code.

Comment: I prefer to compete on the legible code rather than on the shortest code ;) (especially for a beginner)

Answer (score 0):

### Part 1  *and* 2 of your question

The reason you get `NaN` is most probably that if any of the inputs has no `value`, asking for that value returns an empty string (form fields always return strings) `""`. `parseInt("")` returns `NaN`.

Using vanilla ECMAScript 6, the solution is a one-liner with the help of `Array.prototype.reduce`:

```
const sum = [...document.querySelectorAll('.input-n-pro')].reduce((acc, val) => acc += Number(val.value) || 0, 0);
```

For your second question, just use `Array.prototype.map`. Also a one-liner.

```
const theArr = [...document.querySelectorAll('.input-n-pro')].map(x => {return { name: x.name, value: parseInt(x.value) || 0 }});
```

Note: The Array spread operator `[...document.querySelectorAll('.input-n-pro')]` makes an array from the `NodeList` `document.querySelectorAll` returns, so you can use Array methods on the list (like reduce and map).

Example:

```js
calc.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const sum = [...document.querySelectorAll('.input-n-pro')].reduce((acc, val) => acc += Number(val.value) || 0, 0);
  console.log(sum);
})

getArr.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const theArr = [...document.querySelectorAll('.input-n-pro')].map(x => {return { name: x.name, value: parseInt(x.value) || 0 }});
  console.log(theArr);
})
```

```html
<input type="number" value="5" class="input-n-pro" name="a" />
<input type="number" value="3" class="input-n-pro" name="b" />
<!-- lets insert one input that contains no number -->
<input type="text" value="foo" class="input-n-pro" name="m" />
<input type="number" value="2" class="input-n-pro" name="c" />
<input type="number" value="11" class="input-n-pro" name="d" />
<input type="number" class="input-n-pro" name="e" />
<br />
<button id="calc" type="button">Calculate Sum</button>
<button id="getArr" type="button">Get Array of name-value pairs</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

if one of inputs value is empty then parseInt returns NAN. So you can better do a check using IsNan function. if input is empty than assign 0. For example;

var x= parseInt($('#abc').val()); if (isNaN(x)) x = 0;